# Facebook: how to get all People who like a certain URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

As I did a small survey for different things by counting the number of likes of urls I noticed some strange behaviours. I think someone bought likes to push an option.

Now the question: how to get all facebook profiles (fbid) of a certain url for which we did the like button? The URL is outside of Facebook but is within an facebook app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has never and probably never will give user ids of people who like a URL, mainly due to privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try link_stat table of facebook ...
Use this for reference:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

Comment: thanks for that. but it only gives me the number of real likes. thats ok but i need the facebook userid's to check wheter they are fake accounts or not.